# Can we safely represent lamport amounts in javascript using a number?

Tags: web3.js, lamports, supply

Intuition tells me no, as

- total circulating supply of SOL at the time of this writing is `357,157,711.70 ≈ 3.6 * 10^8` according to [Coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/solana/)
- 1 SOL = `1,000,000,000 = 10^9` Lamports
- Max safely representable integer a Number in javascript can represent is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991 ≈ 9 * 10^15`.

If we multiple the first two values we get that if someone wants to perform an operation involving the theoretical max amount of Sol that can be used he'd be interacting with `3.6*10^8 * 10^9  = 3.6 * 10^17 Lamports >> 9 * 10^15`.

Of course I realize that someone interacting with the full circulating supply is extremly unrealistic, but notice how even an interaction with 1% would lead to a loss of precision, which does not seem completely unrealistic to me. In spite of this, the majority of variables (I could find) representing an amount in Lamports in [Solana web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html) uses a Number to represent it.

Is it just assumed that no one will use that much SOL with most of the instructions at once or am I missing something here?

Comment: TCS aside, amounts are represented by `u64` on-chain so in theory, web3.js needs to support up to a max of 2^64 - 1

Comment: Odd as to why the decision for using `Number` over `bigint` was made then

Comment: Everything is slowly transitioning over to using `bigint` everywhere, that's the best option. `number`s are just easier to use for most people, which is why most of the interfaces accept it too.  https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/27440 tracks removing `BN.js`

Comment: Are you aware of any issue tracking the move over from `number` to `bigint`?

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/22606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Number` in JavaScript to represent a value like this is almost always a terrible idea because of the reasons you've laid out. As many of you know, alternate solutions exist:

- Use JavaScript [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)
- Represent a number as a `string` until such time that you need to perform arithmetic on it

We have an [open issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/22606) on `@solana/web3.js` to migrate *off* the JavaScript `Number` type, especially since the JSON RPC itself supports 64-bit integers.